# Can an unprivileged user be given read-only rights to a SYSTEM task?

Tags: windows, security, scheduled-tasks, uac

I have a scheduled task that must run as the SYSTEM account, but I would like to allow unprivileged users the ability to see it.

Specifically, I am interested in users being able to see/get the last run time and the state/status of the specific task.  Obviously, they would need to know the name/location.  They should not have any control over it, and there is no reason they need to see all scheduled tasks or even the other properties of this task (although that would be OK).

Is this possible?  If so, how?

If not, what might be the reasoning why?  It doesn't seem like a security risk.

Thanks.

Comment: On my system, my unprivileged account can see tasks that "use" my username, the `computername$` account and the `INTERACTIVE` and `Users` groups.  I cannot see tasks that run under the `SYSTEM` account unless I am elevated, just as I cannot see tasks that run under other user's accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to grant read rights to the file for the task in the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks` folder.  That can be done as an administrator via the gui, but I did it with a PowerShell script running as SYSTEM (or Admin):

```
$TaskFile = Join-Path $env:SystemRoot "System32\Tasks\$TaskName"
if (Test-Path $TaskFile) {
   $Acl = get-acl -Path $TaskFile
   $rule = New-Object -TypeName system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule -ArgumentList ('Authenticated Users','Read','Allow')
   $Acl.setaccessrule($rule)
   set-acl -Path $TaskFile -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Hope this helps someone.